# Error when deploying rails app on opswork [Unicorn not running]

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, unicorn, aws-opsworks

Hey could anyone here give me some tips regarding deploying a rails app on opswork
I have a load balancer+app+sqlite3 db, when everything is online, nginx log says not able to connect with unicorn, unicorn is not running when I log in to the app server,
It is also not running the database bundle exec rake db:migrate and unicorn is not starting.

I have looked at these links to get an idea of how to install everything. I don't see any failures or errors in setup and configure phase of deployment.

> [Creating custom cookbooks blog](http://mikeprosper.com/2014/01/05/Creating-Custom-Cookbooks-With-AWS-Opsworks/)
>
> [Video on deploying rails app on opswork](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHu8fCp9GR4)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

You have to make sure that you have gem 'unicorn' in your Gemfile and it should start unicorn.